# Print Image One by one C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image

I have written below code to get all images from folder.

Below is the code

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp", "*.jpeg");
```

I got all image names in files.
Now i want to print all images one by one.
I tried below code

```
foreach (var i in files)
{
    objPrintImage = Image.FromFile(i);
    objDimension = new FrameDimension(new System.Guid());
    PrintDocument objPrintDoc = new PrintDocument();
    objPrintDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.objPrintDoc_PrintPage);
    if (objPrintDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        objPrintDoc.Print();
}
```

But getting error **A generic error occurred in GDI+.**

Comment: provide the stacktrace also pls.

Comment: why need  objDimension?

Comment: what you are trying to print? objPrintImage which is image or objPrintDoc?

Comment: @speti43 i found this ocde on net, SO i implemented that. but i got error.

Comment: @NaNa i am trying to print images stored in my temporary folder.

Comment: objPrintImage  is an image. what is objPrintDoc? you are trying to print PrintDocument  object. how objPrintDoc know what is objPrintImage  ?

Comment: @NaNa To Call Print() Method, i have taken objPrintDoc as object Of PrintDocument.

Comment: Ok, Try the new code, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me doesn't throws exception, and print starts:

I saved to jpg files, not jpeg, first is this: [Pencils](http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-07.jpg)

I think the problem is with your image files.

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\", "*.jpg");

        foreach (var i in files)
        {         
            var objPrintDoc = new PrintDocument();
            objPrintDoc.PrintPage += (obj, eve) =>
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(i);
                    Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
                    eve.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
                };
            objPrintDoc.Print();       
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) implements IDisposable, therefore you must dispose your image

```
  foreach (var i in files)
    {
        using(var objPrintImage = Image.FromFile(i))
        {

        objDimension = new FrameDimension(new System.Guid());

        PrintDocument objPrintDoc = new PrintDocument();

        objPrintDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.objPrintDoc_PrintPage);
        if (objPrintDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            objPrintDoc.Print();
        }
        }
    }
```

*Edit* - Just noticed you aren't even using this image in this example?

---

```
public abstract class Image : MarshalByRefObject, 
ISerializable, ICloneable, IDisposable
```

Comment: PrintPage EventHandler will call objPrintDoc_PrintPage event.

Comment: you are saying that i have to dispose image object after i call objPrintDoc.Print()...?

Comment: I'm saying at some point you need to dispose your image, using a using block will do this for you, if there is other code you haven't told us about then just make sure you dispose it correctly, from the code you have given, this is the only thing that could cause a GDI error